# How to write a program which takes root node of the tree as input and returns all leaf nodes

Tags: c#-4.0

[the image takes root node of the tree as input and returns all leaf nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKo4X.jpg)

how to write a program in c# which takes root node of the tree as input and returns all leaf nodes(nodes which have no children also need to implement filtering by the content of the node)